# What should one do when occasionally meeting an acquaintance of theirs with other people being with any of you, potentially unfamiliar with others?

Tags: politeness, social-event

If you stumble upon an acquaintance, then it is normal for you to have a short conversation, or perhaps even spontaneously plan to do something together right away. But if there are people with you who don’t know your acquaintance (or anyone who is with them) or people with them who don’t know you (or anyone who is with you), this is, of course, a whole different kind of situation.

What is the most correct way to behave when it happens? Should you say hi to your acquaintance, or a slight smile is sufficient? Should you have even a 10 second long conversation, or is it better to try to avoid it all? And if they try to talk to you (and this is obvious to you that there are people with you who start to feel uncomfortable), what should you do to politely stop them from having a conversation with you?

Comment: Could you add a location tag? I imagine there is a lot of variation on what is considered "appropriate" around the world.

Comment: Actually I’d like to know what is considered normal for different countries and cultures.

Comment: I don't think that that sort of question will work well for this site-- when a question is too broad it doesn't mesh well with the question-and-answer structure IPS.SE aims to achieve. I strongly encourage you to put some bounds on what you're asking.

Comment: I get the point. Then let’s consider this in the western context. I can’t add a tag though since it requires 150 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually just happened to me this past weekend! My friends and I were walking to our table in a restaurant when I heard someone say "scohe001? Is that you??" and turned to see an old acquaintance from years ago.

While you could try to invite your friends to meet the old acquaintance if you know them well enough and are in a place where you can stop and chat all together, I find that I'm usually not quite outgoing enough to try to facilitate a conversation between two different groups like that.

Instead, I turned to my friends and said:

> You guys can go on ahead and sit down, I'm going to catch up with my old friend for a second. Feel free to start ordering--just save me a slice of bread!

I let my friends know that I needed a second, but that I didn't want to hold them up. This allowed them to avoid a conversation and meeting with my old acquaintance without being rude while also giving me a minute to stop and chat with them.

Comment: That’s good, though probably “you guys *can* go ahead” is better since that leaves them a choice (and if they understand the potential awkwardness of the situation in case they don’t leave you two, they will probably go).

Comment: @Arseny good point! I'll edit to add that.